Save the work ditrct from remote device to local Linux PC device
Remote desktop access :  Scrcpy
Remote device : Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra Phone
Local device :  Ubuntu 24.04 desktop PC (Linux)
While working on remote device, could I save the work direct on local PC to a folder, specially created ?
Please advise.  Thanks in advance

use sftp play app

You can also look into adb commands or MTP protocol
